# Max limit for Text type in Cassandra3.x

Tags: text, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What is the max size for Text column value in cassandra 3.x?

Found [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html) of all the max limits of Cassandra but Text type is not there in the list

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's covered as

> single column value size: 2 GB (1 MB is recommended)

but it's not really recommended to keep large texts (and blobs) in the Cassandra.

Comment: I was expecting something specific to Text column kept searching for that, Thanks.